# axios multipe param request

Tags: javascript, axios, nuxt.js

I'm trying to make a query with axios and parameters
When I perform this code:

```
axios.get('/myApi', { params: { id: [1,2,3] })
```

This puts all in the same url

```
http://localhost/api/myApi?id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3
```

Is there a possibility that I will get a different request each time knowing that my input table will be dynamic?

I would like this dynamically:

```
http://localhost/api/myApi?id[]=1
http://localhost/api/myApi?id[]=3
http://localhost/api/myApi?id[]=3
...
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, You can perform this through loop.

Answer (score 0):

No but you can loop through that url params and request it using axios like :-

```js
for (let i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
  axios.get('/myApi', { params: { id: [i] })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No you have to do that yourself, by issuing multpile requests.

You can utelize `Promise.all` and `map` for that.

`map` is used to issue the individual requests for the passed ids, and to store the Promises returned by `axios` in an array.
And `Promise.all` to wait for all of them to resolve.

```js
function batchRequest(ids) {
   return Promise.all(ids.map( id => {
      return axios.get('/myApi', { params: { id: [id] }})
   }))
}
```

Comment: How to save data in array with this method ?

Comment: @HeurtaultAubin `batchRequest` returns a Promise with an array containing the results of the Promises returned by `axios.get` resolve to. So using `batchRequest([1,2,3]).then(results => console.dir(results))` or `console.dir(await batchRequest([1,2,3]))` will log you an array with those results.